# Placement of standalone script and using django_rq

Tags: django, django-rq

I need to create a standalone script which accesses the database, fetches data from a table and processes it and stores it into another table. I am also using django-rq in order to run this script.

1. Where should place this script in django project structure?
2. Without using views.py, how should I run this script using django-rq?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your case correctly, I would use custom management commands https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: But where do I need to put the django-rq settings?

Comment: @wannaC just in your project settings file as described here https://github.com/ui/django-rq#installation

Answer (score 0):

In one of your views import the scripts' functions and django-rq and continue with your processing in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked this same issue, One added variable was that I wanted to run a job every hour, so in addition to [Django-RQ](https://github.com/W7PEA/django-rq) I am also using [RQ-Scheduler](https://github.com/rq/rq-scheduler).

In this approach, you schedule a function call in the job you create

```
scheduler.schedule(
    scheduled_time=datetime.utcnow(), # Time for first execution, in UTC timezone
    func=func,                     # Function to be queued
    args=[arg1, arg2],             # Arguments passed into function when executed
    kwargs={'foo': 'bar'},         # Keyword arguments passed into function when executed
    interval=60,                   # Time before the function is called again, in seconds
    repeat=10                      # Repeat this number of times (None means repeat forever)
)
```

I created a module `my_helpers.py` in the root of my Django Project which has functions that do the work I want and which scheduled the task as I needed. Then in a separate shell `python manage.py shell` I import the helpers and run my function to scheduled the task.

I hope that helps, its working for me.